# How can I get name by login in ActivityDirectory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I get user name by login in ActiveDirectory?

I am using ActiveDirectory for the first time and I confused :(

This code burns red like fire and I don't know why.
[Photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AGNT.png)

```
public class GetUserController
{
    private static void GetUser(string login)
    {
        string filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})(sAMAccountName={1}))", "person", login);
        string domain = "";
        string[] properties = new string[] { "fullname" };

        DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(adRoot);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
        searcher.Filter = filter;

        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

        string displayName = directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(displayName);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just get an active directory nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a reference to your project to `System.DirectoryServices`. That should correct your errors.

However, there are some things you can make better in your code. Specifically, you can remove your call to `GetDirectoryEntry()`, since that will slow down your code.

When you access the `Properties` of a `DirectoryEntry` object, it first checks to see if the attribute you are looking for is already in its cache. If not, it goes out to AD and asks for *every attribute*. That's a waste, when you're only looking for one.

There is a way to get around that, but in this case, you don't need to use `GetDirectoryEntry()` at all, since you can use the attributes returned by the search. So just ask the search to return `displayName`, and use the value from the `SearchResult`:

```cs
public class GetUserController
{
    private static void GetUser(string login)
    {
        string filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})(sAMAccountName={1}))", "person", login);
        string domain = "";
        string[] properties = new string[] { "displayName" };

        DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(adRoot);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
        searcher.Filter = filter;

        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

        string displayName = result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(displayName);
    } 
}
```

The only reason to use [`GetDirectoryEntry()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry) is if you are going to make a change to the object you just found.

If you're going to be doing more coding with Active Directory, I wrote an article about improving performance that might help you out: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)